# Printing the name of a variable

Tags: python

I am a programmer new to python trying to write a simple test1() function that uses arg (or *arg)  to print out how it was called using the "name" of the argument passed to it, not the content of the list or any other variable that I am passing.

The following example:

```
def test1(arg):

    print "name of arg is %r" % arg


alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c']

test1(alphabet) # prints name of arg is ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want it to print out: name of arg is alphabet
I researched and tried several things related to using *argv but did not succeed. Can someone shed some light on this?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.
Thanks!

Comment: Python objects are [like stray cats](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-can-my-code-discover-the-name-of-an-object): they don't know or care about their names, and may have multiple names or be nameless.

Comment: This is nowhere near a duplicate. In fact it has nothing to do with *argv* as it's known in programming world

Comment: @TimCastelijns Oops, you're right.  I should have read the question more carefully.  I removed my duplicate comment.  Unfortunately, I cannot remove my flag, but I think the discerning moderator will dismiss my flag.  I apologize, Tom D.

Comment: I don't think this duplicates that. The OP hasn't so much as mentioned command line arguments. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Sorry, the closing is my fault (at least partly).  Can we please get a moderator to reopen?

Answer (score 1):

This is more than a little ugly, but it's one way to achieve what you're after:

```
import traceback
import re

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def test(arg):
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    arg_name = re.sub('test\((.*)\)', '\g<1>', stack[-2][-1])
    print arg_name

test(alphabet)
test('foo')
```

The result of which is

```
alphabet
'foo'
```

Comment: If I ever saw this in production code, I would weep silently. +1

Comment: @AdamSmith: I would weep, but it most definitely would *not* be silently ;)

Comment: @Demian - It's beautiful to me, regular expressions and all !  I have a lot to learn. Cheers!

Comment: @TomD If you learn one thing about programming, make it be to NEVER DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS. Make code that's self-documenting and easy to read. Regular expressions are great and well worth your time to look up, but using them to manually hack apart a stack trace is the definition of ugly, hacky code.

Comment: @AdamSmith - appreciate the sage advice. Even though I am a Python noob, I am a former C/Unix systems programmer who used re's in scripts and editors . For that reason, I really enjoyed Demian's solution. Still, I can't help but wonder if a solution like his should be part of a system library, or would it somehow be non-conforming to Python's methodology regarding names and references?

Comment: Kevin's comment in response to your question is Python's stance on the matter. Keep data out of identifiers, and you'll never need to know what the identifier is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, why you want this, anyway ...

If you want the name of argument available in a function, you have to pass the name of the argument to the function. Python is *call by reference* in all cases.

In your function, `arg` will always be named `arg` inside the function. Its outside variable name is not available inside the function.

```
def test1(arg):
    print "name of arg is %r" % arg
```

However python has variable keyword arguments and there lies a possible solution to your problem. Let me redefine `test1()`:

```
def test1(**kwargs):
   param_name = iter(kwargs).next()
   print "name of parameter is %s" % param_name
```

You can call this function with a keyword argument:

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c']
test1(alphabet=alphabet)
```

Note, however, that what get's printed is not the variable name from *outside* the function, but the name of the keyword.

Comment: dhke, Thanks for the quick help!  The reason I wanted the test1() function was to be able to call it from various places in a large program. Knowing the name or names of the argument(s) passed would help in determining where it was called from. It was going to be a useful log or learning tool. I realize there are other ways to achieve the same results.  Your **kwargs solution will work as well as passing a second argument with a string that tells the name of the arg being passed. Being new to Python, I just thought there might be something else more efficient that I was missing. Thanks again!

Comment: python actually passes object references by value. if it were truly pass by reference, this would work: `j = 61; def f(i): i = 7; f(j); assert(j == 7)`

Comment: @acushner If you want to be that correct, you get pass by reference, but you get a *copy of the reference*, same as e.g. Java does it. C++ of course is a little different.

Comment: yeah, it passes the reference by value.

Comment: @TomD Well. You can always get a the stack frame and find out the hard way, where you are being called from. But that's not terribly efficient.

Comment: @acushner - succinctly stated and I now completely understand. Thank you.

Comment: @dhke - I thought I was trying the stack frame route in some of my attempts by using sys.argv but it did not get me to the right place. With less than a month of python under my belt, I should probably be focused on simpler tasks to debug, reverse engineer and learn the language.  Nevertheless, I learned a lot here. Thanks to all of you! I'll be back.